# Text pushed upwards in inputefield Type Time with Angular V14.2.7

Tags: css, angular-material, input-field

I'm facing the issue that we have a input field type time in which the text is pushed higher than in a normal input field.
I'm aware of the fact that the root cause for this issue probably is the time picker icon coming with the input field, or at least i think it is whats causing all this.
I was wondering if someone came up with a solution for this issue?
[Here a mini Version of my problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mx7ftr?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.css,src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.ts)

I accessed the Icon over the
`input[type='time']::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator selector` and tried to set it either to
`display: none` => removes it fromt the GUI but the increased input height persists
`font-size: 0.5em` => thought i could make it smaller and bringt the input field back to its original height.

The closest to a satisfactory point i came was through
`input { max-height: 1.125em; padding-top: 10px; }`
But with the input field now in line the containing text inside of the input fields of type time are vertically unalligned to their normal counterparts:
[Input field Type Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Rlb.png)
[Normal input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih10F.png)

Is there a fix for it or will i have to enlarge every other input field to accomodate to this annomaly?

Comment: You example doesn't compile as you have a appearance="" attribute which seems to be illegal, this makes it harder for people to start helping you

Comment: Thank you for the hint, i fixed it and it should build as intended again.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wondering, i managed to bypass the issue through editing the positioning of the mat-underline with
`::ng-deep .ClassOfYourInputfield .mat-form-field-underline { top: 2.775em; }`
This worked best without the `appearance="fill"` tag of the MatFormField as the Inputfields height remains too large. As this is only a workaround and probably not feasible for someone who wants the fill styling i'd let the question open.